# Django syncdb locking up on table creation

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb

I've added new models and pushed to our staging server, run syncdb to create their tables, and it locks up. It gets as far as 'Create table photos_photousertag' and postgres output shows the notice for creation of 'photos_photousertag_id_seq', but otherwise i get nothing on either said. I can't ctrl+c the syncdb process and I have no indication of what route to take from here. Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 1):

We use postgres, and while we've not run into this particular issue, there are some steps you may find helpful in debugging:

a. What version of postgres and psycopg2 are you using? For that matter, what version of django?

b. Try running the syncdb command with the "--verbosity=2" option to show all output.

c. Find the SQL that django is generating by running the "manage.py sql " command. Run the CREATE TABLE statements for your new models in the postgres shell and see what develops.

d. Turn the error logging, statement logging, and server status logging on postgres way up to see if you can catch any particular messages.

In the past, we've usually found that either option b or option c points out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this as well, and it turned out to just be a plain old lock on that particular table, unrelated to Django. Once that cleared the sync went through just fine.

Try querying the table that the sync is getting stuck on and make sure that's working correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

Strange here too, but **simply restarting the PostgreSQL service (or server)** solved it. I'd tried manually pasting the table creation code in psql too, but that wasn't solving it either (well, no way it could if it was a lock thing) - so I just used the restart:

> systemctl restart postgresql.service

that's on my Suse box.

Am not sure whether *reloading* the service/server might lift existing table locks too?